# Line not getting in scatterplot R

Tags: r, scatter-plot, mgcv

I have an issue getting a line in R. I have the following code:

```
#7.4
NFull <- tp$ntest;
Ni <- 0.7*log(tp$ntest);
#install.packages(mgcv)
library(mgcv)
plot(tp$pos ~ tp$dateno, main="Deltaudglatning")
xval <- with(tp, seq(min(tp$dateno), max(tp$dateno), length.out = 224))


fitgam <- gam(tp$pos ~ s(tp$dateno, k=4)+offset(Ni), tp, family=quasipoisson, method="REML")
summary(fitgam)
lines(xval, predict(fitgam, data.frame(xval),type="response"), col="green")
```

I would like to get it in this scatterplot:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Can anyone help here?

Screenshot of my data, which has 224 lines in total:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Link to data:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoOKR.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFycU.png

Comment: Provide example data please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you did not name the variables you try to predict for in the data frame you give the predict function.

Here is an example with (obviously quite different) simulated data that should work:

```r
tp <- data.frame(date = as.Date('2020-04-01') + 0:223,
                 dateno = 1:224,
                 ntest = sample(1000:7000, 224),
                 pos = sample(140:500,224,T))

NFull <- tp$ntest;
Ni <- 0.7*log(tp$ntest);
#install.packages(mgcv)
library(mgcv)
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> This is mgcv 1.8-33. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.
plot(tp$pos ~ tp$dateno, main="Deltaudglatning")
xval <- with(tp, seq(min(tp$dateno), max(tp$dateno), length.out = 224))


fitgam <- gam(pos ~ s(dateno, k=4)+offset(Ni), tp, family=quasipoisson, method="REML")
summary(fitgam)
#> 
#> Family: quasipoisson 
#> Link function: log 
#> 
#> Formula:
#> pos ~ s(dateno, k = 4) + offset(Ni)
#> 
#> Parametric coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) -0.008858   0.033060  -0.268    0.789
#> 
#> Approximate significance of smooth terms:
#>           edf Ref.df     F p-value
#> s(dateno)   1      1 1.422   0.234
#> 
#> R-sq.(adj) =  -1.03   Deviance explained = 0.629%
#> -REML = 607.37  Scale est. = 79.403    n = 224
lines(xval, predict(fitgam, data.frame(dateno = xval),type="response"), col="green")
#> Warning in predict.gam(fitgam, data.frame(dateno = xval), type = "response"): not all required variables have been supplied in  newdata!
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>